# Referencing Nested Type in Visual Studio 2008 XAML Designer

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2008, xaml

With the following resource definition

```
<ObjectDataProvider MethodName="GetValues" ObjectType="{x:Type sys:Enum}" x:Key="AccountTypeValues">
    <ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
        <x:Type TypeName="domain:Account+AccountType" />
    </ObjectDataProvider.MethodParameters>
</ObjectDataProvider>
```

the designer complains that "Type 'Account+AccountType' was not found." However, the nested type exists and code complies and runs without a problem. Since the designer thinks the XAML is incorrect, it won't display a graphical rendition of the XAML.

What do I need to do to get the designer to recognize Account+AccountType as valid? I'd really like the visual part of the designer to work.

Thank you,
Ben

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is a known bug in Visual Studio.  From http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/12f3e120-e217-4eee-ab49-490b70031806/:

> We had somebody look at the use of
>   {x:Type Foo+Bar} pattern and test it
>   in VS2010 and Blend4. It appears that
>   it works fine at Runtime, CompileTime,
>   in Blend 4, but fails in VS2010's WPF
>   Designer.
>
> We've filed a bug, and routed it to
>   the WPF Designer team.

See also http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/361509/xaml-designer-cannot-handle-typename-with-nested-classes.

You could create a static property that calls `Enum.GetValues(typeof(Account.AccountType))` and bind to that instead of using an `ObjectDataProvider`.  Or, if you control the types, you could move the enum outside the class.